# Android GCM instanceID.getToken() throws TIMEOUT exception on Gingerbread

Tags: android, exception, timeout, google-cloud-messaging, android-2.3-gingerbread

As the title indicates I get a `TIMEOUT` exception when trying to get token using Google Cloud Messaging on API 10 emulator. I have added my google account on the device, checked that "Sync" is ON, also added the
`<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>` in the manifest in the receiver and still cannot find out what is causing this:

```
11-25 17:35:00.896 29750-29774/com.example.alexis.myapplication W/InstanceID/Rpc: No response android.os.ConditionVariable@b667bc18
11-25 17:35:00.896 29750-29774/com.example.alexis.myapplication E/MYAPP: TIMEOUT
```

Here is the manifest declaration for permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission android:name="com.example.alexis.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.alexis.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And receiver:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.alexis.myapplication" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: I am using genymotion emulator with 2.3.7, I don't have a hardware device to test.

Comment: Try to use the official repo here: https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android/gcm-demo

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it failed to getToken cause I was using the emulator. Got a hardware device today for testing and it worked immediately and as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a hardware device and everything worked so it was emulator's fault.